# How to create an array of objects with key/value pairs from selector variables in $each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a new object in jquery with the values of multiple selectors. For example:

```
loopSelector = $('.myClass');

loopSelector.each(function(i, elem) {

  var1 = $(elem).parents('li').text();
  var2 = $(elem).parents('p').text();

  var newArray = [{
    animal: var1
    age: var2
  }];
  console.log(newArray);
}
```

In the console I get:

- **Array(1)**
- 0: {animal: 'cat', age: 12}
- **Array(1)**
- 0: {animal: 'dog', age: 5}
- **Array(1)**
- 0: {animal: 'goat', age: 7}

But when I try to `console.log(newArray.age);`  I get `undefined` 3 times. My goal is to compare all of the objects by the value of age.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `newArray[0].age`  It's an array...

Comment: it's an array since you have to define `[0]` after newArray

Comment: Also if you are going to want to compare all the ages, you have an issue in that you are not persisting the array outside the each.  You are creating a new single element array each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to create an array of the same elements selected, just with a different data representation for each, consider using [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) instead of `.each()`:

```js
loopSelector = $('.myClass');

var array = loopSelector.map(function (i, elem) {
  var animal = $(elem).parents('li').text();
  var age = $(elem).parents('p').text();

  return {
    animal: animal,
    age: age
  };
}).get();

console.log(array);
```

Note the use of [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) at the end (as pointed out by Taplar in the comments), which converts the jQuery object into a regular Javascript array.

Or with some fancy ES6 features thrown in to tidy things up a little:

```js
const array = $('.myClass').map((i, elem) => {
  const animal = $(elem).parents('li').text();
  const age = $(elem).parents('p').text();

  return { animal, age };
}).get();

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code snippet to access object directly:

```
loopSelector = $('.myClass');

var newArray = [];

loopSelector.each(function(i, elem) {

  var obj = {};
  var1 = $(elem).parents('li').text();
  var2 = $(elem).parents('p').text(); 

  obj.animal = var1;
  obj.age = var2;

  newArray.push(obj);
}

newArray.map(val => {
  //Here your will be able to access directly to objects with key name.
  console.log(val)
});
```